# Variant record instead of overloaded object type?

Tags: delphi, overloading, record, variant, tobject

I'm working on a problem in which I need to dynamically size an array, upon which numerous operations are needed. I have successfully coded two classes, t_one and t_two:

```
tarray1 : array of longint;
tarray2 : array of single;
t_one = class(tobject)
  Public
  Myarray1 : tarray1;
  constructor create;
  destructor destroy;
  procedure oneofmany; 
end;
t_two = class(tobject)
  Public
  Myarray1 : tarray2;
  constructor create;
  destructor destroy;
  procedure oneofmany; 
end;
```

The two objects have nearly identical code except that Myarray1 is an array of single in one case and an array of longint in the other. Is the only way to make this into a single object to use variant arrays (which will slow things down)? A variant record is inefficient for what I'm doing as well. If I could say

```
case mysituation of
  integerdata : (myarray1 : tarray1);
  realdata: (myarray1 : tarray2);
end;
```

that would be what I mean, but obviously that syntax is anathema. Of course, there are places where method calls and function results need to know the data type, but once defined they're consistent. Thoughts? Use a variant array and suffer the slowdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible approaches - make the only class using generics

```
  TA<T> = class
  public
     Arr : TArray<T>;
     destructor destroy;override;
  end;
...
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: TA<Integer>;
  B: TA<Single>;
begin
  A := TA<Integer>.Create;
  B := TA<Single>.Create;
  A.Arr := [1,2,3];
  B.Arr := [Pi, Ln(2)];
  Memo1.Lines.Add(A.Arr[0].ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(B.Arr[0].ToString);
end;
```

Comment: @user3670958: Notice that MBo marked the destructor with the `override` directive. That's important.

Comment: This is obviously the right starting point. It gets tricky of course if you need to perform arithmetic on the items in the array. Generics is pretty much useless for that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer leads to solutions that get quite convoluted. There's a reason for strong typing! Because one cannot have multiple function return types with the same function name, one gets bogged down in similarly named functions for different argument types. If you try

```
var
  mypointer : pointer;
begin
  case argtype of
    integer: mypointer := @A;
    single : mypointer := @B;
end;
```

then you still need to type mypointer every time you use it. Turns out not to help a whole lot.